# How do I resolve localRayletDiedError when using Modin with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, ray, modin

I am trying to use the Modin engine to process a large dataframe:

```
df.head(20):

Unnamed: 0                       game score home_odds draw_odds away_odds country                 league             datetime
0            0  Sport Recife - Imperatriz   2:2      1.36      4.31      7.66  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-07 00:00:00
1            1           ABC - America RN   2:1      2.62      3.30      2.48  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 22:00:00
2            2  Frei Paulistano - Nautico   0:2      5.19      3.58      1.62  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 00:00:00
3            3    Botafogo PB - Confianca   1:1      2.06      3.16       3.5  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 22:00:00
4            4          Fortaleza - Ceara   1:1      2.19      2.98      3.38  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 22:00:00
5            5             River-PI - CSA   3:1      3.41      3.07       2.1  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 20:00:00
6            6     Sport Recife - Vitoria   1:1      1.92      3.20      3.93  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 20:00:00
7            7           CRB - Santa Cruz   1:0      2.22      3.06      3.18  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-29 23:30:00
8            8         Bahia - Imperatriz   2:0      1.31      4.75      8.55  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-29 00:00:00
9            9    Ceara - Frei Paulistano   2:2       1.2      5.43     12.94  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 22:00:00
10          10            Confianca - ABC   1:0      2.09      3.01      3.58  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 00:00:00
11          11   America RN - Botafogo PB   0:0      2.14      3.30      3.11  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 22:00:00
12          12         CSA - Sport Recife   0:1      2.63      3.04      2.62  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 22:00:00
13          13         Santa Cruz - Bahia   0:0      3.72      3.22      1.96  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 20:00:00
14          14        Vitoria - Fortaleza   0:0      3.13      3.02      2.27  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 20:00:00
15          15         Nautico - River-PI   1:1      1.44      4.06      6.19  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-23 23:30:00
16          16           Imperatriz - CRB   2:1      2.34      2.94      3.08  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-21 23:00:00
17          17       Nautico - Campinense   2:0       1.4      4.18      7.26  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2019-05-16 00:30:00
18          18          CRB - Juazeirense   2:1       1.4      4.19      7.32  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2019-05-14 23:00:00
19          19             ABC - AE Altos   2:0      1.44      3.83      7.02  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2019-05-08 22:30:00
```

My code:

```
import os
import ray
ray.init()
os.environ["MODIN_ENGINE"] = "ray"
import modin.pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"data.csv", low_memory=False)
df['game'] = df['game'].astype(str).str.replace('(\(\w+\))', '', regex=True)
df['league'] = df['league'].astype(str).str.replace('(\s\d+\S\d+)$', '', regex=True)
df['league'] = df['league'].astype(str).str.replace('é', 'e', regex=True)
df['game'] = df['game'].astype(str).str.replace('(\s\d+\S\d+)$', '', regex=True)
df[['home_team', 'away_team']] = df['game'].str.split(' - ', expand=True, n=1)
df[['home_score', 'away_score']] = df['score'].str.split(':', expand=True)
df['away_score'] = df['away_score'].astype(str).str.replace('[a-zA-Z\s\D]', '', regex=True)
print (df.head())
```

I am getting the below error:

```
2022-04-30 14:40:13,260 INFO services.py:1462 -- View the Ray dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:8265
(pid=) G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\ray\dashboard\modules\reporter\reporter_agent.py:41: UserWarning: `gpustat` package is not installed. GPU monitoring is not available. To have full functionality of the dashboard please install `pip install ray[default]`.)
(pid=)   "`gpustat` package is not installed. GPU monitoring is "
UserWarning: `read_*` implementation has mismatches with pandas:
Data types of partitions are different! Please refer to the troubleshooting section of the Modin documentation to fix this issue.
UserWarning: `Series.<lambda>` defaulting to pandas implementation.
To request implementation, send an email to feature_requests@modin.org.
UserWarning: Distributing <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> object. This may take some time.
UserWarning: `DataFrame.setitem_unhashable_key` defaulting to pandas implementation.
UserWarning: `Series.<lambda>` defaulting to pandas implementation.
(pid=) [2022-04-30 14:40:43,683 E 13292 5940] (raylet.exe) agent_manager.cc:107: The raylet exited immediately because the Ray agent failed. The raylet fate shares with the agent. This can happen because the Ray agent was unexpectedly killed or failed. See `dashboard_agent.log` for the root cause.
(apply_func pid=5756) Stack (most recent call first):
(apply_func pid=5756)   File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\ray\_private\utils.py", line 116 in push_error_to_driver
(apply_func pid=5756)   File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\ray\worker.py", line 449 in main_loop
(apply_func pid=5756)   File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\ray\workers/default_worker.py", line 235 in <module>
(apply_func pid=12968) 
(apply_func pid=16252) 
(apply_func pid=11964) 
(apply_func pid=2452) 
(apply_func pid=13388) 
(apply_func pid=13240) 
(apply_func pid=10024) 
(apply_func pid=1708) 
(apply_func pid=12056) 
(apply_func pid=2868) 
(apply_func pid=12020) 
(apply_func pid=14356) 
(apply_list_of_funcs pid=15872) 
(apply_func pid=4964) 
(apply_func pid=3292) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/My Drive/Predictor/Code/1. Main/3. Creating updated training data.py", line 25, in <module>
    df[['home_score', 'away_score']] = df['score'].str.split(':', expand=True)
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\modin\pandas\series_utils.py", line 154, in split
    pandas.Series.str.split, pat=pat, n=n, expand=expand
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\modin\pandas\series_utils.py", line 452, in _default_to_pandas
    lambda series: op(series.str, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\modin\pandas\base.py", line 460, in _default_to_pandas
    pandas_obj = self._to_pandas()
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\modin\pandas\series.py", line 2182, in _to_pandas
    df = self._query_compiler.to_pandas()
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\modin\core\storage_formats\pandas\query_compiler.py", line 256, in to_pandas
    return self._modin_frame.to_pandas()
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\modin\core\dataframe\pandas\dataframe\dataframe.py", line 2255, in to_pandas
    df = self._partition_mgr_cls.to_pandas(self._partitions)
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\modin\core\dataframe\pandas\partitioning\partition_manager.py", line 644, in to_pandas
    retrieved_objects = [[obj.to_pandas() for obj in part] for part in partitions]
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\modin\core\dataframe\pandas\partitioning\partition_manager.py", line 644, in <listcomp>
    retrieved_objects = [[obj.to_pandas() for obj in part] for part in partitions]
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\modin\core\dataframe\pandas\partitioning\partition_manager.py", line 644, in <listcomp>
    retrieved_objects = [[obj.to_pandas() for obj in part] for part in partitions]
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\modin\core\execution\ray\implementations\pandas_on_ray\partitioning\partition.py", line 193, in to_pandas
    dataframe = self.get()
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\modin\core\execution\ray\implementations\pandas_on_ray\partitioning\partition.py", line 75, in get
    return ray.get(self.oid)
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\ray\_private\client_mode_hook.py", line 105, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\My Drive\Predictor\venv\lib\site-packages\ray\worker.py", line 1811, in get
    raise value
ray.exceptions.LocalRayletDiedError: The task's local raylet died. Check raylet.out for more information.
```

dashboard_agent.log:

```
2022-04-30 14:40:23,268 INFO agent.py:109 -- Dashboard agent grpc address: 127.0.0.1:56809
2022-04-30 14:40:23,269 INFO utils.py:99 -- Get all modules by type: DashboardAgentModule
2022-04-30 14:40:27,915 INFO utils.py:132 -- Available modules: [<class 'ray.dashboard.modules.event.event_agent.EventAgent'>, <class 'ray.dashboard.modules.log.log_agent.LogAgent'>, <class 'ray.dashboard.modules.reporter.reporter_agent.ReporterAgent'>, <class 'ray.dashboard.modules.runtime_env.runtime_env_agent.RuntimeEnvAgent'>]
2022-04-30 14:40:27,915 INFO agent.py:130 -- Loading DashboardAgentModule: <class 'ray.dashboard.modules.event.event_agent.EventAgent'>
2022-04-30 14:40:27,916 INFO event_agent.py:28 -- Event agent cache buffer size: 10240
2022-04-30 14:40:27,916 INFO agent.py:130 -- Loading DashboardAgentModule: <class 'ray.dashboard.modules.log.log_agent.LogAgent'>
2022-04-30 14:40:27,916 INFO agent.py:130 -- Loading DashboardAgentModule: <class 'ray.dashboard.modules.reporter.reporter_agent.ReporterAgent'>
2022-04-30 14:40:27,920 INFO agent.py:130 -- Loading DashboardAgentModule: <class 'ray.dashboard.modules.runtime_env.runtime_env_agent.RuntimeEnvAgent'>
2022-04-30 14:40:27,922 INFO agent.py:134 -- Loaded 4 modules.
2022-04-30 14:40:27,957 INFO http_server_agent.py:64 -- Dashboard agent http address: 127.0.0.1:50885
2022-04-30 14:40:27,957 INFO http_server_agent.py:70 -- <ResourceRoute [GET] <StaticResource  /logs -> WindowsPath('C:/Users/harsh/AppData/Local/Temp/ray/session_2022-04-30_14-40-04_775382_10900/logs')> -> <bound method StaticResource._handle of <StaticResource  /logs -> WindowsPath('C:/Users/harsh/AppData/Local/Temp/ray/session_2022-04-30_14-40-04_775382_10900/logs')>>
2022-04-30 14:40:27,957 INFO http_server_agent.py:70 -- <ResourceRoute [OPTIONS] <StaticResource  /logs -> WindowsPath('C:/Users/harsh/AppData/Local/Temp/ray/session_2022-04-30_14-40-04_775382_10900/logs')> -> <bound method _PreflightHandler._preflight_handler of <aiohttp_cors.cors_config._CorsConfigImpl object at 0x0000017A1C01F0C8>>
2022-04-30 14:40:27,957 INFO http_server_agent.py:71 -- Registered 2 routes.
2022-04-30 14:40:27,961 INFO event_agent.py:45 -- Report events to b'127.0.0.1:50687'
2022-04-30 14:40:27,961 INFO event_utils.py:127 -- Monitor events logs modified after 1651291825.2349648 on C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2022-04-30_14-40-04_775382_10900\logs\events, the source types are ['CORE_WORKER', 'COMMON', 'RAYLET'].
```

[raylet.out](https://pastebin.com/teSBwx4a)

While I am new to Modin, how do I resolve this error?

I am running the code on Win 11

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sit amet felis id erat pharetra ornare in at enim. Nulla libero felis, dapibus quis porta sed, tristique eget quam. Fusce vitae risus nibh. Morbi facilisis metus in commodo pellentesque. Aliquam consequat massa at porta vehicula. Cras in ipsum lacinia, venenatis orci ut, mollis nulla. Phasellus sit amet tempus dui, sit amet pretium leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec condimentum justo vel elit dapibus pulvinar. Vestibulum sed sem sit amet magna gravida mollis ut eget sem. Mauris erat sapien, dapibus vel mauris nec, efficitur sodales quam. Donec dignissim tincidunt ipsum vel dapibus.

Answer (score 1):

From the raylet logs, it looks like an out of memory error occurred.

Line 226:

```
[2022-04-30 14:40:24,100 I 13292 16268] (raylet.exe) object_store.cc:35: Object store current usage 8e-09 / 8.22634 GB.
```

Then line 230:

```
[2022-04-30 14:40:33,337 I 13292 13512] (raylet.exe) object_buffer_pool.cc:153: Not enough memory to create requested object 359ec6ce30d3ca2dffffffffffffffffffffffff0100000001000000, aborting
```

I would first try rerunning this while observing the [Ray dashboard](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/ray-dashboard.html) to see if the memory is indeed approaching 8GB, and asking whether your data size is close to 8GB.

If memory does seem like the issue, you can try running this script on a machine with more memory (on a cloud instance). If you are limited to running locally, perhaps you could try running `ray.init()` with greater memory limits, like [here](https://docs.ray.io/en/releases-0.8.2/memory-management.html). Although not ideal, consider running with a subset of the data (twice). Finally, consider opening an issue in the Modin github: https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues.

On a side note, from the standard output, it looks like the line that crashes is

```py
df[['home_score', 'away_score']] = df['score'].str.split(':', expand=True)
```

which creates two columns from one.

The previous line

```py
df[['home_team', 'away_team']] = df['game'].str.split(' - ', expand=True, n=1)
```

also creates two columns from one - I wonder if you have the raylet logs from that line.

Comment: Thank you. The issue that I noticed is that I was running pycharm in a virtual environment. When I ran the same code using system interpreter, it worked. Probably pycharm has not yet been optimised for Windows 11. But, changing the interpreter settings helped.

Comment: ray link is dead!